# passing data as "xml" rathar than as object

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to choose between "xml" data passing, or "object" data passing. ( Say when passing data along with the customevents ). What is efficient ?

V.

Answer (score 1):

XML is good choice when you need to transfer data between two different technologies, these which does not support same data types natively, so you can "unify" data with XML for each of them. Then both sides can parse XML and make native data types from it, in order to process(if needed).

It's true that flash have very native support for XML (dynamic XML and XMLList classes) it supports even XML literals.

I think you should choose from following conditions:

- If you initially know what fields your data will have for example
  `red, green` fields and you know that these fields will not change.

You better use predefined Class structure.

- If your data will change it's fields dynamically, for example
  sometimes it will have only `red, green` fields and in some cases
  `red, green, blue`.
- If you plan in further using your flash application with other
  technology/service.

Use XML.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use XML unless you *really* have to!**

XML is best used when transferring data to/from the flash application, but it's VERY slow to use internally:

Personally, I would always use Vectors, Dictionaries, or struct-type Classes to pass data around internally, never XML!

http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1187
(According to this site, several hundred times slower!)

Dictionaries cannot be declared inline like Objects can, but the ability to use objects as keys as well as values is really useful (not to mention weak references) - it can take a while to see why, or when you'd need this, but once you do you'll see why it's so handy!

NB There ARE times when XML may be useful - I have used it in an application with an 'undo/save' function, as portions of the (and sometimes the whole) program needed to describe their state, or configure themselves from an XML description. It was useful in this instance as:

a) The data was being sent intermittently to a server, or read from it. As the data was already in XML format, it required no conversion.

b) It's much more readable, as the save output was also needed for debugging it was worth sacrificing a bit of speed over.

c) The user would only be undoing/redoing actions infrequently. A slight drag of a fraction of a second did not matter, but if you want to optimise your code, you shouldn't use it.

Hope this helps